# Application crashes when using Google Maps v2 on most devices

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

Im trying to code some application that uses Google Maps API. The map is shown in the main activity.

On some phones, including the emulator, the application crashes immediately after starting. The only phone it works with is my Galaxy S1, which runs CM10.1 (4.2.2).

It crashes on my HTC DESIRE HD (4.2.2 as well)

MainActivity.java:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void ToastLoadShout(String msg){Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

      static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
      static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
      static final LatLng gps = new LatLng(0, 0);
      static double lat=0.0;
      static double lon=0.0;
      private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        turnGPSOn();

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
           // Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
           //    .title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Free shyt")
                .snippet("Come and take this shit")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            ImageView locate;
            locate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.locate);
            locate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ReNewCoordinates();

                    if (lat==0&&lon==0)
                        ToastLoadShout("Try again in a few seconds.");
                    else
                    {
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,lon), 10));
                    ToastLoadShout("your location is: "+lat+" , "+lon);
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

                    Marker loc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat,lon))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.loc)));
                    }
                }
            });

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(50.909474,13.917618), 10000));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(1), 20, null);

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,lon), 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            //map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
            //ToastLoadShout("your location is: "+lat+" , "+lon);
            ImageView add;
            add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);
            add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
            });
    }

     private void turnGPSOn() {

            String provider = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
                final Intent poke = new Intent();
                poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                        "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
                poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
                sendBroadcast(poke);
                ToastLoadShout("Turning GPS on..");
            }
        }

     public void ReNewCoordinates(){
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Define a listener that responds to location updates
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                    lat = (location.getLatitude());
                    lon = (location.getLongitude());
                }
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras) {}};
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have the logcat of the HTC here:

```
08-01 18:46:29.929: I/Process(4007): Sending signal. PID: 4007 SIG: 9
08-01 18:46:32.031: D/skia(4024): new locale en-Latn-GB
08-01 18:46:32.141: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4024): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 18:46:32.151: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4024): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 18:46:32.151: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4024): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 18:46:32.161: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4024): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 18:46:32.171: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4024): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 18:46:32.231: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(4024): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 18:46:32.231: D/AndroidRuntime(4024): Shutting down VM
08-01 18:46:32.231: W/dalvikvm(4024): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b10930)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.free/com.example.free.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.x.b(Unknown Source)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.aX(Unknown Source)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Unknown Source)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at com.example.free.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
08-01 18:46:32.241: E/AndroidRuntime(4024):     ... 11 more
```

And the emulator's logcat:

```
08-01 15:27:48.565: E/Trace(981): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-01 15:27:49.305: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(981): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:27:49.326: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(981): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:27:49.345: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(981): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:27:49.366: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(981): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:27:49.385: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(981): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:27:49.565: D/dalvikvm(981): GC_CONCURRENT freed 200K, 4% free 8223K/8519K, paused 36ms+5ms, total 163ms
08-01 15:27:49.565: D/dalvikvm(981): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 88ms
08-01 15:27:49.745: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(981): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:27:49.745: D/AndroidRuntime(981): Shutting down VM
08-01 15:27:49.755: W/dalvikvm(981): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.free/com.example.free.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.google.android.gms.internal.x.b(Unknown Source)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.aX(Unknown Source)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Unknown Source)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at com.example.free.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-01 15:27:49.765: E/AndroidRuntime(981):  ... 11 more
08-01 15:28:19.685: I/Process(981): Sending signal. PID: 981 SIG: 9
08-01 15:52:15.355: E/Trace(1058): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-01 15:52:16.015: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1058): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:52:16.025: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1058): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:52:16.055: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1058): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:52:16.075: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1058): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:52:16.095: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1058): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:52:16.265: D/dalvikvm(1058): GC_CONCURRENT freed 206K, 4% free 8223K/8519K, paused 76ms+5ms, total 157ms
08-01 15:52:16.265: D/dalvikvm(1058): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 31ms
08-01 15:52:16.326: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(1058): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 1
08-01 15:52:16.335: D/AndroidRuntime(1058): Shutting down VM
08-01 15:52:16.335: W/dalvikvm(1058): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.free/com.example.free.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.x.b(Unknown Source)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.aX(Unknown Source)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Unknown Source)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at com.example.free.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:52)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
08-01 15:52:16.355: E/AndroidRuntime(1058):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Did you enable GL mode? How GoogleMap2 library included into you project?

Comment: I just imported the google services: like that: Import → Android → Existing Android Code into Workspace.

Comment: How can I enable that GL mode? Havent heard about it..

Comment: For enabling GL mode put this code into AndroidManifest
<uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true"/>
For well working with google service you must import whole google-play-services_lib into to your project like library.

Answer (score 6):

Just do the following to check if google play services are available:

```
int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getApplicationContext());
    if(status == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        //Success! Do what you want

    }else{
        GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, this, status);
    }
```

It will check for google play services and if are not available it will prompt user to download them from google play

Answer (score 3):

It sounds as though the phones you're testing on don't have the latest Google Play Services pre-req's installed.

If you take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) you'll find a section discussing how you can ensure that devices have the google play service APK installed and if not, direct the user to install it.

Also note that the emulator isn't supported on emulators running an API platform less than Andorid 4.2.2 (referenced [here](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html) in the first section)

Comment: How do i implement those methods? Do I have to add a library or something? because it's telling me there isnt such a thing as "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable();" for example.

Comment: Is there another way to use a map and avoid asking the user to download the sdk?

Comment: "isGooglePlayServicesAvailable()" is found in com.google.android.gms.common as shown here: http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/GooglePlayServicesUtil.html#isGooglePlayServicesAvailable%28android.content.Context%29

That should be part of the Google Play Services library if you'd added it to your project.

If not, it can be found in {SDK Dir}\extras\google

Comment: As for another way, not really - at least not officially. You wont be able to search for it on the Play Market either as it's hidden. It's not the SDK, it's the Google Play Services APK which is required for the user to even use the latest Google Maps v2 implementation so most users should already have it anyway

Comment: I imported it, but what do I have to import in the code..? I mean.. what Import _____; should I use?

Comment: Another question, If I want to run it on my HTC DESIRE HD, How can I download the lastest SDK? or is it pushed automatically?

Comment: In order to get the latest SDK, use the SDK Manager. In Windows, press Start button, then search "SDK Manager"

Comment: @NirPes In order to call `GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(context)` you will have to use `import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil;`

Answer (score 2):

I have the same exception on my app:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
```

In my case, I have to call `BitmapDescriptorFactory` static method after initializing the Google Map object.

Read the comments:

```
// This line initilizes the map asynchronously. It requires implementation
// of OnMapReadyCallback interface.
// And when it is inizilized, it calls onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);


// The following method is implemented in my activity
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    ... some code ...
    currentLocationIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.report_location_current)
    ... some code ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
GoogleApiAvailability googleApiAvailability=GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

int status=googleApiAvailability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());

        if (status != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            int requestCode = 10;
            Dialog dialog = googleApiAvailability.getErrorDialog(getActivity(),status,requestCode);
            dialog.show();
        }else{}
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer [here](http://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html) to check for Google Play Services available on your phone. If you encounter an error then it will display an error dialog returned from Google Play Services. I have worked on my application with Google Maps v2 on Samsung Galaxy S3 and its working fine.