# How to make Google maps in my application compatible with almost any android version?

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator, android-mapview

I'm working on an application that involves google maps.

I [tried](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17998958/application-crushes-when-using-google-maps-v2-on-most-devices) to work with the new V2 google maps, but it turns out that only 4.2.2 based devices can run it.

How can I make an all android version-completable maps for my app?

Thank you very much.

It DOES NOT WORK with my HTC DESIRE HD (4.2.2)

The code:

```
package com.example.free;

import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public void ToastLoadShout(String msg){Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

      static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(53.558, 9.927);
      static final LatLng KIEL = new LatLng(53.551, 9.993);
      static final LatLng gps = new LatLng(0, 0);
      static double lat=0.0;
      static double lon=0.0;
      private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        turnGPSOn();

        map = ((MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                .getMap();
           // Marker hamburg = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG)
           //    .title("Hamburg"));
            Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("Free shyt")
                .snippet("Come and take this shit")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));

            ImageView locate;
            locate = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.locate);
            locate.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    ReNewCoordinates();

                    if (lat==0&&lon==0)
                        ToastLoadShout("Try again in a few seconds.");
                    else
                    {
                    map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,lon), 10));
                    ToastLoadShout("your location is: "+lat+" , "+lon);
                    map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);

                    Marker loc = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(lat,lon))
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                        .fromResource(R.drawable.loc)));
                    }
                }
            });

            map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(50.909474,13.917618), 10000));
            map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(1), 20, null);

            // Move the camera instantly to hamburg with a zoom of 15.
            //map.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(lat,lon), 15));

            // Zoom in, animating the camera.
            //map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
            //ToastLoadShout("your location is: "+lat+" , "+lon);
            ImageView add;
            add = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.add);
            add.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Add.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    }
            });
    }


    private void turnGPSOn() {

            String provider = android.provider.Settings.Secure.getString(
                    getContentResolver(),
                    android.provider.Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
            if (!provider.contains("gps")) { // if gps is disabled
                final Intent poke = new Intent();
                poke.setClassName("com.android.settings",
                        "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
                poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
                poke.setData(Uri.parse("3"));
                sendBroadcast(poke);
                ToastLoadShout("Turning GPS on..");
            }
        }
     /*private void getLocation() {
            // Get the location manager
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) 
                    getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
            Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
            String bestProvider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, false);
            Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            LocationListener loc_listener = new LocationListener() {

                public void onLocationChanged(Location l) {}

                public void onProviderEnabled(String p) {}

                public void onProviderDisabled(String p) {}

                public void onStatusChanged(String p, int status, Bundle extras) {}
            };
            locationManager
                    .requestLocationUpdates(bestProvider, 0, 0, loc_listener);
            location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(bestProvider);
            try {
                lat = location.getLatitude();
                lon = location.getLongitude();
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                lat = -1.0;
                lon = -1.0;
            }
        }
     */
     public void ReNewCoordinates(){
            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            // Define a listener that responds to location updates
            LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
                public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                    // Called when a new location is found by the network location provider.
                    lat = (location.getLatitude());
                    lon = (location.getLongitude());
                }
                public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
                public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
                public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,Bundle extras) {}};
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
            }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

the logcat using the HTC:

```
08-01 21:47:39.645: I/Process(5270): Sending signal. PID: 5270 SIG: 9
08-01 21:47:43.980: D/skia(5310): new locale en-Latn-GB
08-01 21:47:44.120: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5310): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 21:47:44.130: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5310): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 21:47:44.130: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5310): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 21:47:44.140: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5310): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 21:47:44.150: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5310): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 21:47:44.210: W/GooglePlayServicesUtil(5310): Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
08-01 21:47:44.210: D/AndroidRuntime(5310): Shutting down VM
08-01 21:47:44.210: W/dalvikvm(5310): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40b10930)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.free/com.example.free.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2308)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2358)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:153)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1247)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5227)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:795)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:562)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at com.google.android.gms.internal.x.b(Unknown Source)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.aX(Unknown Source)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(Unknown Source)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at com.example.free.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2262)
08-01 21:47:44.220: E/AndroidRuntime(5310):     ... 11 more
```

line 53:

```
 Marker kiel = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                .position(KIEL)
                .title("title")
                .snippet("description")
                .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory
                    .fromResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher)));
```

Answer (score 0):

From the logcat you present you have two different errors:

```
Google Play services out of date.  Requires 3159100 but found 2012110
```

That indicates that the Google play services installed on this device are not up to date and you should update it. You can try to remove it and download it again from google play store.

the second error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: IBitmapDescriptorFactory is not initialized
```

indicates that you are using an `IBitmapDescriptorFactory` object that you didn't initialize.

Comment: Ty. How can I update the google services? And how can I fix the second error?

Comment: Usually it should update automatically, like I said you can try to remove Google play service and to re-download it again using the Google play store. As for the second error, I need to see your code but it's clear that you need to initialize this object.

Comment: Ive added the code to the questnion. I cant find Google Play Services in the market using the device.. I can only see it when browsing with my PC... How can I update it?

Comment: If you remove google play service from the device and run an appreciation with google maps, the Google maps fragment will present you a button to download google play services.

Comment: Ok. What about the code? I installed the Services through my PC and it works.

Comment: you can't test Google Maps on the emulator, you have to test it on a real device.

Comment: Okay, what about the code? You said I didnt initialize something? ty

Comment: what happens on line 53 of your activity? from you logcat you have some problem there: at com.example.free.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:53)

Comment: Its just a map marker that im not using.. I will now add it to the question.